# Converting source code to syntax-highlighted PDFs

Tags: linux, source-code, pdf-generation, highlighting

I'm looking for a command-line Unix/Linux program that can take source code in any common programming language and produce a good-looking syntax-highlighted PDF, preferrably with line numbers and with long lines wrapped appropriately.  Unicode support is also desirable.

I'm aware of `enscript`, but its output isn't all that appealing, and it doesn't seem to support Unicode input.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be well worth your time to explore the Python [Sphinx-Doc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) infrastructure but for just what you asked for you could simply use [Pygments](https://pygments.org/) & [rst2pdf](https://github.com/ralsina/rst2pdf):

With a python 3 installation you can simply `pip install rst2pdf Pygmments` *rst2pdf will also install ReportLab.*

Pygments is a syntax highlighting package written in Python.

It is a generic syntax highlighter for general use in all kinds of software
such as forum systems, wikis or other applications that need to prettify
source code. Highlights are:

- a wide range of common languages and markup formats is supported
- special attention is paid to details, increasing quality by a fair amount
- support for new languages and formats are added easily
- a number of output formats, presently HTML, LaTeX, RTF, SVG, all image
  formats that PIL supports, and ANSI sequences
- it is usable as a command-line tool and as a library
- ... and it highlights even Brainfuck!

Pygments gives you a command line utility `pygmentize`  Of course since you can get LaTex output you can then use the standard system tools to generate PDF files but rst2pdf will allow you to go to pdf directly.